# Closing connection and removing from vector halts program

Tags: c++, networking

I have a socket number stored among other variables in a vector tuples where each tuple represents a connection. When I try to close a connection from this vector, by closing the socket then erasing the tuple, the program halts with no error thrown.

I've tried putting print statements around the erase line and it never makes it through. I've tried using a debugger to avail; the debugger doesn't detect anything being thrown. Adding a breakpoint in front of the erase allowed the program to work fine so I figured a sleep should have the same effect, but with a sleep, it still halts.

Here's where I try to close and erase:

Note that `expired_connections` is a vector of `outgoing_connections` iterators that have been marked for erasing.

```
outgoing_connection_mutex.lock();
for (int i = 0; i < expired_connections.size(); i++) {
    auto e = expired_connections[i] - i;
    std::cout << "Closing " << std::get<1>(*e) << std::endl;
    *std::get<3>(*e) = !*std::get<3>(*e);
    if (!close(std::get<1>(*e))) {
        outgoing_connections.erase(e);  // <--- HALTS HERE
    }
}
outgoing_connection_mutex.unlock();
```

Here's the format of `outgoing_connections`:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::future<std::string>, int, std::chrono::time_point<high_resolution_clock>, std::shared_ptr<bool> > > outgoing_connections;  // Connection future, socket, timeout timer, needs to exists
```

Comment: `auto e = expired_connections[i] - i;` – there's no `operator-` for std::tuple. Did you define your own? Otherwise, that should not even compile. I personally would consider using `std::remove_if` with custom comparator (don't forget to apply [erase-remove-idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)!). Closing the connection probably is best done inside a destructor (would mean that you replace the tuple with your custom class), but would be possible in the comparator (lambda), too...

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned `expired_connections` is a vector of iterators, that's using the `operator-` for an iterator.

Comment: Are you aware that iterators expire if you erase elements in front of them? Still using them results in undefined behaviour! You need to make sure you erase in strictly descending order to keep that safe.

Comment: Still erasing again and again will move subsequent elements towards front – again and again. Pretty inefficient. Consider dropping that expired_connections vector and instead add another 'expired' property to the tuple. Then use `std::remove_if` as proposed above on that vector.

Comment: Alternatively you can make `outgoing_connections` a `std::list`, this one's iterators are robust against list's modifications (unless you delete the element an iterator refers to directly).

Comment: Even deleting in reverse it still halts. Also, I tested the same logic in an independent program with just a vector of ints and this logic for deleting worked just fine. While it may be less efficient it should still work. I am going to use `remove_if` instead however, so thank you for that advice.

Comment: Are you sure that the iterators are in right order to do the way you do? – Imagine very first connection expires (the one of `outgoing_connections.front()`), but some other ones expired before. Then you'd try to erase e. g. `outgoing_connections.begin - 7`!!! Whichever direction you choose, you need to make sure that *all* iterators are sorted appropriately!

Comment: Perhaps, I'm going to try `remove_if` in a bit, that should resolve that if it's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto e = expired_connections[i] - i;
```

If you need to subtract an offset, then you removed an iterator *in front of* – but that means that all subsequent iterators got invalidated! You cannot use them any more without invoking undefined behaviour!

Now lets assume above *would* be valid. Then you still have another problem:

```
outgoing_connections.push_back(makeConnection());
outgoing_connections.push_back(makeConnection());
// now for any reason, second connection expires before first one!!!
expired_connections.push_back(outgoing_connections.begin() + 1);
expired_connections.push_back(outgoing_connections.begin());
```

You would now try to erase `outgoing_connections.begin() - 1`! Again undefined behaviour.

You would have to *sort* the iterators and then remove in correct order, such that you remove backmost iterator first. That would at least avoid undefined behaviour, but is pretty inefficient: Every time you erase one element from the vector, you move all subsequent ones towards front. Multiple moves over possibly large ranges...

Best you can do is dropping that `expired_connections` vector and instead mark the connections themselves expired:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<
    std::future<std::string>,                       // Connection future
    int,                                            // socket
    std::chrono::time_point<high_resolution_clock>, // timeout timer
    std::shared_ptr<bool>                           // needs to exist
    bool                                            // expired
> outgoing_connections;
```

(Honestly, a separate class/struct with *named* members would be better choide!)

Then you can use [erase-remove-idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) in combination with `std::remove_if` to drop closed connections:

```
outgoing_connections.erase
(
    std::remove_if
    (
        outgoing_connections.begin(), outgoing_connections.end(),
        [](auto& connection)
        {
            // minimalistic variant, if need be add output back again...
            return connection.isExpired && !close(connection.fd);
        };
    ), // returns an iterator to new end
    outgoing_connections.end()
);
```

The advantage of is that `std::remove_if` (as well as `std::remove`) start removing at front of vector and move all elements that shall remain towards front – possibly skipping multiple positions at once, so every element is moved just once, below how that function *could* be implemented:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Condition>
Iterator remove_if(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Condition condition)
{
    Iterator pos = begin;
    for(; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        if(!condition)
        {
            // element shall remain!
            if(begin != pos)
                *pos++ = *begin;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

You see: Every element is touched just once... So far, though, elements are only moved (or copied, if no move assignment available), but surplus elements at the end are not removed. That's why you still need the call to `erase`.